# Ubuntu Touch Wifi Password Issues on Nexus 7

Tags: wireless, networking, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I have just installed Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 7. I use Ubuntu on my PC and all of my work computers and love it which is why I decided to try it out on the Nexus. It has all loaded and I can connect to open wifi networks but when I choose a password protected wifi network there is nowhere to enter a wifi password. I have looked and not seen anyone else with this issue. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has existed in the last few daily builds, up to and including latest 'current'.

It is now fixed, in build: **20130816.2**

### ***WORK AROUND***

Wait a few days, and try again.

### **OR**

Try re-installing, using 'pending' build:

**`phablet-flash cdimage-touch -b --pending`**

---

The FTP server where these files are downloaded from:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/